# How can I check the format of an E-Mail address?

Tags: c#, validation, if-statement

I am building an e-mail validation program.

How can I check if my E-Mail has 3 letters before the @ and 2 letters after the "." I tried `else if` but it didn't work.

```cs
string rightPassword = "red@gmx.to";
string enter = Console.ReadLine();

string red = rightPassword.Substring(0, 3);
string to = rightPassword.Substring(8);

int lengthRed = red.Length;
int lengthTo = to.Length;
do
{
    Console.Write("Write the E-Mail: ");
    enter = Console.ReadLine();

    if (rightPassword == enter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Right Password");
    }
    else if (lengthRed < 3 ) // I have to check if it has 3 letters before the @//
    {

      Console.WriteLine("You need 3 letters before the @")
    }
    else if (lengthTo < 2)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("You need 2 letter after the ".")     
    }
} while (enter != "enter");
```

Comment: You are calling `Console.ReadLine();` twice. After the second one you are not calculating `red`, `to`, `lengthRed` and `lengthTo` again. These calculations should be inside the loop after the ReadLine. The first Readline is superfluous.

Comment: It's very rare that regex validation is the right tool for email addresses. If you need a *valid* email address, send them a validation email. If they can complete the validation invoked by the email, the address is valid. If they cannot, then who cares whether or not it matches a *potentially valid* email address.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) for pattern matching.

You should use [this](https://regex101.com/r/ojIL6N/1) regex to achieve what you want: `^\w{3}@\w+.\w{2}$`
[image: explanation]

code example:

```
string email = "abc@aa.co";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\w{3}@\w+.\w{2}$");
Match match = regex.Match(email);
if(match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine("Email matches pattern");
else Console.WriteLine("Email does not matches pattern");
```

Comment: Alrigh,t thank you. I will use the one from RedFox. I am not familiar with Regex

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Regular Expressions, even though it is highly encouraged, you can add a method:

```
public static bool HasValidUsername(string email)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (!email[i].IsLetter())
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And use the method in your code:

```
else if (!HasValidUsername(enter))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You need 3 letters before the @");
}
```

But keep in mind, that the example above will not validate numbers or symbols. You could use `email[i].IsSymbol()` or `email[i].IsNumber()` to check for that.

---

Note:
`x@com` is a valid email adress for a domain registrar. That said, most of them use a subdomain for their email. `x@x.com` for example. Handling all real world email cases is not as trivial as it might seem.

Comment: Thanks Redwolf, I was looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Char.IsLetter()` method

```
public bool IsValidEmail(string email)
{
    return email.Length > 2 Char.IsLetter(str[0]) && Char.IsLetter(str[1]) && Char.IsLetter(str[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Split.

Something like

```
string red = rightPassword.Split('@')[0];
string to = rightPassword.Split('.').Last();
```

you'll also be able to check what's after the "@" if you use

```
string red = rightPassword.Split('@')[0];
string gmx= rightPassword.Split('@')[1];
string to = rightPassword.Split('.').Last();
```